# Bremsstrahlung in peskin and schroder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, perturbation-theory

I'm studying chapter 6 of Peskin and Schroeder on bremsstrahlung. Here is the Feynman diagram on page 182

[image]

My questions are:

1. Why are there two photon lines attached to the dark disk? (I circled the photon lines I meant.)
2. I see bremsstrahlung is described by one electron going in, one electron and a photon coming out. I attempt to use Wick's theorem to the expression

$$\langle 0|a_p b_k (-ie)\overline{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi A_\mu\,\,(-ie)\overline{\psi}\gamma^\nu\psi A_\nu a^\dagger_p|0\rangle.$$

Here I use $a$ to denote annilation/creation operators for electrons and $b$ to denote annilation/creation operators for photons. Because there's an odd number of external legs, shouldn't this be 0? Since we are going to be left with some uncontracted terms.

Comment: Something unspecified and possibly very complicated happens in the blob (which evidently causes two photons to come out, though this is an arbitrary detail), but what it precisely is doesn't matter. The point of this passage is that Peskin is comparing the amplitudes for "something complicated happening" to "something complicated happening, plus there's a soft photon of momentum $k$ emitted".

Comment: Also, Bresmsstrahlung is not defined as $e^- \to e^- + \gamma$. There always needs to be something else in the process, or else it's simply forbidden by momentum conservation. That "something else", whatever it happens to be, is what's represented by the blob.

Comment: @knzhou I see, what are the complicated blob though? Can the blob be taken in to consideration in the calculations?